# I want to save my Rscript but it keeps returning an error

Tags: r, save

I am trying to save an R script in my project folder, where the R directory is located. I have tried several options for saving but it keeps returning the following error:
Error saving xxxxxxxxfilexxxxxx. The system can not find the file specified.

I have tried save as, save, blah blah blah, knitting the document to pdf or word, nothing works because the file does not exist, despite the fact that I created the project

Comment: Perhaps the directory was deleted? Or locked? Or on a external drive that got disconnected? Can you navigate to the directory in your OS? Is the problem just that directory - are you able to save the script someplace else? If the problem is just that directory, is there anything special about it, like is it OneDrive or something?